# Mongodb 4+ findOneAndUpdate() returnNewDocument not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After reading the general documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.findOneAndUpdate/
And not being able to find the function in the native driver documentation.

Updated the node driver from 3.4 to 4.1
Server is running 4.4.7

Cannot for the life of me get `returnNewDocument` to work.
I've confirmed `upsert` and `projection` work.
I've tried `new:true` a 2018 SO answer, but this isn't in the new docs.
It shows the old document regardless of the `projection` qualifiers.

```
exports.setEmailKey = async (email, key) => {
    try {
        return await ucol.findOneAndUpdate(
            { email:email }, 
            { $set: { 
                email_key: key, 
                email_key_time: getEpoc() 
                }
            },
            {   upsert: true,
                returnNewDocument: true,
                projection: {
                    _id: 1,
                    email: 1,
                    email_key: 1,     // shows old value
                    email_key_time: 1 // shows old value
                }
            }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        log('setEmailKey() Failed', e)
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The node.js driver is not the same as Realm.

In the node driver, the [findOneAndUpdateOptions](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/findoneandupdateoptions.html) type does not have a `returnNewDocument` option, but it does have a `returnDocument` option with possible values of `'before'`(default) or `'after'`.

Comment: Thanks!! That link is a gold mine. Wonder why I couldn't find links to it.