# I use mongoDB's findOneAndUpdate with { returnOriginal: false } but it doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

When I use `MongoDB`'s `findOneAndUpdate` and I have declaration `{ returnOriginal: false }` but it doesn't work and when I update successfully it returns me stale data I expect to return the data after update.
My `MongoDB` version is "4.1.0".

```html
const update = async (id, data) => {
  try {
    const result = await getDB()
      .collection(columnCollectionName)
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: ObjectId(id) },
        { $set: data },
        { returnOriginal: false }
      );
    return result.value;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb 4+ findOneAndUpdate() returnNewDocument not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660059/mongodb-4-findoneandupdate-returnnewdocument-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says we need to use **{new : true}**, but it didn't really work for me.
What worked for me is - **{returnDocument:"after"}** (another option instead of "after" is "before")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{ returnOriginal: false }` use `{ new: true }`